# SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError: Operation timeout

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, sequelize.js

Please understand this scenario and I need the help to solve this issue.

If anyone can help me identify the issue and solve I will reward him on fiverrr upto $15.

I am working with a backend that is using mysql and sequelize db. For about six months it was working fine. for you information I am using a shared hosting server with the following resources.

Statics of my servers are here.

```
Physical Memory Usage 3.04 GB / 6 GB (50.68%)
--
Entry Processes 137 / 400 (34.25%)
Disk Usage 287.92 GB / 1,000 GB (28.79%)
MySQL® Disk Usage 189.78 GB / 901.86 GB (21.04%)
Bandwidth 28.32 GB / ∞
Addon Domains 0 / ∞
Subdomains 3 / ∞
Alias Domains 0 / ∞
Email Accounts 1 / ∞
Mailing Lists 0 / ∞
Autoresponders 0 / ∞
Forwarders 0 / ∞
Email Filters 0 / ∞
MySQL® Databases 4 / ∞
CPU Usage0 / 100 (0%)
I/O Usage0 bytes/s / 200 MB/s (0%)
```

All other functions are working fine. But whenever I add these queries after some time 24 hours, 48 hours or a maximum of 72 hours, the server goes down with this error:

> SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError: Operation timeout
>
> at ConnectionManager.getConnection (/home/truecall/nodevenv/public_html/truecaller/14/lib/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:206:15)

Here is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "truecaller",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./app.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon ./app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "agentkeepalive": "^4.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "joi": "^17.11.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.7",
    "rootpath": "^0.1.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.35.1",
    "sequelize-auto": "^0.8.8"
  }
}
```

Here is the search file after running this route I am getting this error:

```
const { getNetwork } = require("./network.service");
const sequelize = require("../_helpers/sequelize");
module.exports = {
  getAll,
  getById,
  search,
  update,
  delete: _delete,
  getContactDetailsFromDatabase1,
  getContactDetailsFromDatabase2,
};
async function getAll() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    reject({
      status: false,
      message: "GET is not allowed",
    });
  });
}

async function getById(id) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    reject({
      status: false,
      message: "GET_BY_ID is not allowed",
    });
  });
}

// async function search(params) {
//   return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
//     // return getContactDetailsFromDatabase2(params)
//     //   .then((data) => {
//     //     resolve(data);
//     //   })
//     //  .catch(async (err) => {
//         resolve({
//           status: false,
//           db: "db2",
//           message: "Not Data Found",
//           appuser: false,
//           appuserresults: null,
//           results: null,
//           location_info: "No Network" // await getNetwork(params),
//         });
//     //  });
//   });
// }

async function search(params) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    return checkifAppUser(params).then((data) => {
      resolve(data)
    }).catch(() => {
      getContactDetailsFromDatabase1(params).then((data) => {
        resolve(data)
      }).catch((err) => {
        getContactDetailsFromDatabase2(params).then((data) => {
          resolve(data)
        }).catch(async (err) => {
          resolve({
            status: false,
            db: "db2",
            message: "Not Data Found",
            appuser: false,
            appuserresults: null,
            results: null,
            location_info: await getNetwork(params),
          });
        })
      })
    })
  });
}

async function update() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    reject({
      status: false,
      message: "PUT is not allowed",
    });
  });
}

async function _delete() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    reject({
      status: false,
      message: "DELETE is not allowed",
    });
  });
}

async function checkifAppUser(params) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query(
        `select users.*, countries.name, countries.iso2, filtered_contacts.name_check as spam_count from users  join countries on users.country_id = countries.id join filtered_contacts on filtered_contacts.mobile_number = users.mobile_number where users.mobile_number = ${params.mobile_number}`
      );

      if (results.length > 0) {
        
        resolve({
          status: true,
          db: "db1",
          appuser: true,
          message: "Contact found successfully",
          appuserresults: results[0],
          results:null,
          network: await getNetwork(params),
        });
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      reject();
    }
  });
}

async function getContactDetailsFromDatabase1(params) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query(
        `![Capture](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/assets/72066902/bb024ea5-9bce-409d-87e6-c1fc76d89bbf)`
      );

      if (results.length > 0) {
        resolve({
          status: true,
          db: "db1",
          appuser: false,
          message: "Contact found successfully",
          appuserresults: null,
          results: {
            filtered_contact_id: results[0].filtered_contact_id,
            filtered_contact_name: results[0].filtered_contact_name,
            spam_check:
              results[0].spam_check == null ? 0 : results[0].spam_check,
            suggested_names: await removeAttributes(results.reverse()),
          },
          location_info: await getNetwork(params),
        });
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      reject();
    }
  });
}

async function getContactDetailsFromDatabase2(params) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query(
      `SELECT id , personName from truecall_central_caller_database.contactsdb where nationalNumber = '${params.mobile_number}' and countryId = (SELECT id from countries WHERE countries.iso2 = '${params.iso2}') LIMIT 1`
    );
    if (results.length > 0) {
      resolve({
        status: true,
        db: "db2",
        appuser: false,
        message: "Contact found successfully",
        appuserresults: null,
        results: {
          filtered_contact_id: results[0].id,
          filtered_contact_name: results[0].personName,
          spam_check: 0,
          suggested_names: [
            {
              suggested_name: results[0].personName,
              count: 1,
            },
          ],
        },
        location_info: await getNetwork(params),
      });
    } else {
      const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query(
        `SELECT id , personName from truecall_central_caller_database.contactsdb2 where nationalNumber = '${params.mobile_number}' and countryId = (SELECT id from countries WHERE countries.iso2 = '${params.iso2}') LIMIT 1`
      );
      if (results.length > 0) {
        resolve({
          status: true,
          db: "db2",
          appuser: false,
          message: "Contact found successfully",
          appuserresults: null,
          results: {
            filtered_contact_id: results[0].id,
            filtered_contact_name: results[0].personName,
            spam_check: 0,
            suggested_names: [
              {
                suggested_name: results[0].personName,
                count: 1,
              },
            ],
          },
          location_info: await getNetwork(params),
        });
      } else {
        const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query(
          `SELECT id , personName from truecall_central_caller_database.contactsdb3 where nationalNumber = '${params.mobile_number}' and countryId = (SELECT id from countries WHERE countries.iso2 = '${params.iso2}') LIMIT 1`
        );
        if (results.length > 0) {
          resolve({
            status: true,
            db: "db2",
            appuser: false,
            message: "Contact found successfully",
            appuserresults: null,
            results: {
              filtered_contact_id: results[0].id,
              filtered_contact_name: results[0].personName,
              spam_check: 0,
              suggested_names: [
                {
                  suggested_name: results[0].personName,
                  count: 1,
                },
              ],
            },
            location_info: await getNetwork(params),
          });
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      }
    }
  });
}





async function removeAttributes(arr) {
  await arr.forEach((obj) => {
    delete obj.filtered_contact_id, delete obj.filtered_contact_name;
    delete obj.spam_check;
  });
  return arr;
}
```

Sequelize connection file `db.js`

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const config = require("../../config.json");

const { database, user, password } = config.database;

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    host:"localhost",
    database:database, 
    user:user, 
    password:password, 
    dialect: "mysql",
    logging: false,
      pool: {
        max: 1000,
        min: 10,  
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 1000
      }
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

I have checked the mysql process List it has no pending process or queries.

I have tests all the queries it has execution time about 0.0035

The nodeJS app has about 2 million users and per hours request to the search query are about 1 million.

We have been stuck here for more than 2 months now. Can anyone here help us? You can ask for more information I will provide it. Thanks

[image: Query Image]

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME and BEFORE your expected crash
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please also post last 100 lines from your error.log when you are running after your next crash, please.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of  EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (rest of your query);  and the COMPLETE query you are running, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck i will update it today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After along time finally this issue has been fixed. i have removed sequilize from my code and used mysql2 connectionPool.

The main issue was sequilize was that there was raw quires and for raw quires it does not close connections.

third issue was with mysql server. time to kill the idle threads was too hight. ie 28100 seconds. after set it to 60 sececonds all the issues were gone and now its working fine.